# Linear Algebra progression in our times

Tags: linear-algebra, research

I know that Linear Algebra is relatively new branch of Mathematics.

I wonder, Is there any significant progress with Linear Algebra in our time? Are there any major questions which haven't solved yet?

Comment: do you consider random matrices to belong to linear algebra?

Comment: relatively new? ["The study of linear algebra first emerged from the study of determinants, which were used to solve systems of linear equations. Determinants were used by Leibniz in **1693**"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra#History)

Comment: Indeed, relatively new. It depends on your scale of course

Comment: @IttayWeiss, You tell me. I'm just a freshman :)

Comment: As far as I know, a lot of progress has been made in the study of numerical methods for solutions of large systems of linear equations. While most methods (conjugate gradients, BiCGStab, GMRES, ...) work quite well for "nice systems" (symmetric, positive definite, or at least normal), there are many open questions about when and how fast these methods converge for non-normal matrices and which preconditioners to use for large systems that comes, for example, from PDE's such as Navier-Stokes equations.

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable enough to comment on the significance of recent results in linear algebra, but you'll find plenty of these as exercises in Prasolov's _Problems and theorems in linear algebra_.

Comment: The problem of classifying pairs of commuting matrices up to simultaneous conjugation is generally considered to be impossible.  (Equivalently, classifying representations of the algebra $k[x,y]$).  In a way you might also consider much of representation theory to be an extension of linear algebra (and other things), as well as fields surrounding the theory of algebraic groups.  Many homogeneous spaces from algebraic geometry can be understood from the standpoint of linear algebra.

Comment: What can be classified as a linear algebra problem is ambiguous. The Riemann hypothesis, if I remember correctly, can be reformulated as an eigenvalue problem for the leading principal submatrices of an infinite matrix.

Comment: A list of interesting problems can be found in Zhan's survey paper [*"Open problems in matrix theory"*](http://math.ecnu.edu.cn/~zhan/papers/ZhanICCM.pdf). Problems 1 (Hadamard conjecture) and 3 (the "permanent-on-top" conjecture) are well known. Problem 17 (additive decomposition of real matrices into orthogonal matrices) is accessible to virtually every first year student of linear algebra. The list, however, is neither exhaustive nor representative, of course. E.g. it has not any problems in numerical linear algebra, noncommutative linear algebra or the theory of random matrices.